# NodeJS object undefined when call a function to console.log(`${note.title}`)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just want check my notes.j that return a notes.logNote(note) when I call: `node app.js add --title=" "`
, if the `--title=" "` was declared so it wouldn't written over in notes-data.json.

this is my app.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const os = require('os');
const _ = require('lodash');
const yargs = require('yargs');
const notes = require('./notes.js')
const argv = yargs.argv;

var command = argv._[0];
console.log(' Your Command: ', command);
console.log(' Your processes is: ',process.argv);
console.log(' Your Yargs is: ', argv);

if (command === 'add') {
    var note = notes.addNote(argv.title, argv.body);
    if (note) {
        console.log(" You write the new object in notes");
        notes.logNote(note);
    } else {
        console.log(" You write an exist objects in node");
        console.log(' -- which is');
        notes.logNote(note);
        // here I can't call note.title = undifiend same with note.body = undifined
        // I want to log the title if was exists
         // console.log(` Title: ${note.title}`);
         // console.log(` body: ${note.body}`);
    } else {
      console.log(' Your command not in my list command that i made');
};
```

and I called some few function from notes.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
var fetchNotes = () => {
  try {
      var noteString = fs.readFileSync('notes-data.json');
      return JSON.parse(noteString);
  } catch (e) {
      return [];
  }
};    

var saveNotes = (notes) => {
    fs.writeFileSync('notes-data.json', JSON.stringify(notes));
}; 

var logNote = (note) => {
console.log(' -- which is');
console.log(` Title: ${note.title}`);
console.log(` body: ${note.body}`);
};        

var addNote = (title, body) => {
  var notes = fetchNotes();
  var note = {
      title,
      body
  };       
  var duplicatesNotes = notes.filter((note) => note.title === title);
  console.log( "If you get message your input object was duplicated");
  if(duplicatesNotes.length === 0) {
      notes.push(note);
      saveNotes(notes);
      return note;
    }
};

module.exports = {
    addNote,
    logNote
};
```

So I called twice `node   app.js --title="drunk" --body="weed"` and result get error `title` from `${note.title}` was undefined.

Need some advise though, thanks for reading

Comment: Your code calls `notes.logNote(note)` even when the `if (note)` test fails.

Comment: @pointy  yeah that's it, should i put also `else if (note)'`?

Comment: If the `if (note)` test fails, then you already know that `note` is `undefined` or `null`.

Comment: I want to declare also if the note was exist. how to figure out?

Comment: You already have figured it out. `if (note)` will *succeed* when `addNote()` returns a note, and it will *fail* (go to the `else`) when `addNote()` returns `undefined`. If you call `logNote(note)` when `note` is `undefined` you'll get exactly the error you're seeing.

Comment: @pointy thanks for your answer and advise, I just debugging, So no need to worried if the `note` was exist. You help me out

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
      var noteString = fs.readFileSync('notes-data.json');
      return JSON.parse(noteString);
  } catch (e) {
      return [];
  }
```

fs will return buffer and you cannot parse the buffer, you have to stringify  the buffer first and then parse it.

```
var note=fs.readFileSync('notes-data.json')
var noteString=JSON.stringify(note)
return JSON.parse(noteString)
```